# Error in Retrieving Binary Image using generic Handler

Tags: c#, binary-data

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    static DataTable dt;
    string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceUrl"].ToString();

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string id = context.Request.QueryString["id"]; //get the querystring value that was pass on the ImageURL (see GridView MarkUp in Page1.aspx)

        if (id != null)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            string json = ClsUtility.HttpGet(url + "Services/service.svc/ProductS/" + id);
            json = Regex.Unescape(json);
            dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '"', '.' }), typeof(DataTable));

            //Get Image Data
            byte[] file = (byte[])Convert.FromBase64String(dt.Rows[0]["ProductImage"].ToString());
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(file, 78, file.Length - 78); 

            memoryStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(file);
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Here I am not getting any error and not showing the image

In .aspx I tried to access the image files as

```
<asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx?id=" + Eval("ProductRowId")%>' />
```

Not Product Name tell me what the mistake I did in the handler

Comment: Why aren't you create an image with src equal for your image?

Comment: I need to bind Dyanamic Data..in Grid if only one image  i can simply assign to image with src,,,

Comment: `<img srv='<%# Eval("ProductBrandName")%>' runat="server" />

Comment: Sry I added previous Item template...What I did Actually was Edited

Comment: please reply me to solve the issue........not getting the answer for the edited query

Comment: In your code your Handler class is called `Handler` and `EcommerceHandler`. Is this correct? Another question: If you try to access to link to your handler directly in the browser (like `EcommerceHandler.ashx?id=1`) it works?

Comment: It is Handler.ashx when I am truying to acees the link in browser it says ...Image Cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: Tried to acees the link http://localhost:1415/Handler.ashx?id=1  it says .Image Cannot be displayed because it contains errors